# RegEx - problem with multiline input

Tags: java, regex

I have a String with multiline content and want to select a multiline region, preferably using a regular expression (just because I'm trying to understand Java RegEx at the moment).

Consider the input like:

```
Line 1
abc START def
Line 2
Line 3
gh END jklm
Line 4
```

Assuming `START` and `END` are unique and the start/end markers for the region, I'd like to create a pattern/matcher to get the result:

```
 def
Line 2
Line 3
gh
```

My current attempt is

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("START(.*)END");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find())
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

But the result is

```
gh
```

So `m.start()` seems to point at the beginning of the line that contains the 'end marker'. I tried to add `Pattern.MULTILINE` to the compile call but that (alone) didn't change anything.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `Pattern.DOTALL`, so `.` matches newline characters.  `MULTILINE` addresses a different issue, the `^` and `$` anchors.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("START(.*)END", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Thanks! Runs like a charm now :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to set Pattern.DOTALL (so you can match end of line characters with your . wildcard), see this test:

```
@Test
public void testMultilineRegex() throws Exception {
    final String input = "Line 1\nabc START def\nLine 2\nLine 3\ngh END jklm\nLine 4";
    final String expected = " def\nLine 2\nLine 3\ngh ";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("START(.*)END", Pattern.DOTALL);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, m.group(1));
    } else {
        Assert.fail("pattern not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Runs like a charm now :)

Answer (score 1):

The regex metachar `.` does not match a newline. You can try the regex:

```
START([\w\W]*)END
```

which uses `[\w\W]` in place of `.`.

`[\w\W]` is a char class to match a word-char and a non-word-char, so effectively matches everything.

Comment: Thanks! In my special case using flag fits slightly better into my existing code, but I'll definitly keep this solution in mind.